# mongoose overriding original object instead of updating

Tags: mongodb, object, mongoose, insert-update

I have something like this:

```
  pinnedKpi: {
    Ver01: { type: Array },
    Ver02: { type: Array },
    Ver03: { type: Array },
    Ver04: { type: Array }
  },
```

when I update this object, on say the Ver01 key i get something like this back:

```
 pinnedKpi: {
         Ver01: [1,2,3,4],
      }
```

it overrides the entire data structure, and now I can't access my other `VerX` keys

Here is my update code

```
 app.post('/savePinned', (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: req.body.email },
    {
      $set: {
        pinnedKpi: { [`Ver0${req.body.kpiVersion}`]: req.body.pinnedKpi }
      }
    },
    { upsert: true, new: true },
    function(err, user) {
      if (err) console.log('error saving pinned kpi', err);
      res.send(user.pinnedKpi[`Ver0${req.body.kpiVersion}`]);
    }
  );
});
```

I have tried it with only upsert:true, only new:true, and niether option.. It still won't update just one key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
  app.post('/savePinned', (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: req.body.email },
    {
      $set: {
        ["pinnedKpi.Ver0"+req.body.kpiVersion]: req.body.pinnedKpi
      }
    },
    { upsert: true, new: true },
    function(err, user) {
      if (err) console.log('error saving pinned kpi', err);
      res.send(user.pinnedKpi[`Ver0${req.body.kpiVersion}`]);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot-notation to access and set fields deep inside objects

```
const updateUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { email: req.body.email },
  { $set: { "pinnedKpi.Ver01":  ["oooooo", "77777"] }},
  { upsert: true, new: true }
)
```